# Python odeint usage

Tags: python, scipy

Can someone tell me how to put in the parameters for the odeint function for the python to get the integral.

I am trying to get the integral of e^x from 0 to 2 but I am not sure how to put in the parameters. The documentation isnt all that clear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to calculate integrals, rather than to solve differential equations, you can also use

```
from numpy import exp
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f(x):
    return exp(x)

result, error = quad(f, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that assumes y(0) = 1.

```
import scipy
import scipy.integrate


def integrateExp(y0, a, b):
  limits = [a, b]
  integral = scipy.integrate.odeint(lambda y, t : scipy.exp(t), y0, limits)
  return integral[1]

print integrateExp(1, 0, 2)
```

The first argument should take (y,t) and return the corresponding derivative.  I used a lambda here since d/dt exp(t) is trivial.

Comment: Hello, Would it be possible for you to tell me how I can use this within a function. By that I mean can I define a function like def calc(x, a, b): and paste that code in there? I cant figure out how to place the function within the odeint if a function is specified in the parameters. It says x isnt declared

Comment: Hi thanks. I have been playing with the same thing but i cant figure out how to put in other functions.. like x**2 from 0-1..
please check out this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372321/python-using-lambda-within-a-function/

Comment: Hi Kartik, you need to calculate the derivative yourself, either analytically or numerically.