# Python Using Lambda Within a Function

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to create a function called `calc(f,a,b)` where x is an equation with the variable f and I want to put this code within the function.

```
   def calc(f, a, b):
       limits = [a, b]
       integral = odeint(lambda y, x : f, 0, limits)

       return integral[1]
```

This function gets the integral using the built in odeint function.
This is what I am trying to do

```
print calc(x**2, 0, 1)
```

where `x^2` is the function to be integrated. My problem is that this function (`x**2`)needs to be passed on to the `odeint` function right after `y, x: f` where f after the semicolon is the `f` from the `calc(f,a,b)`

what I cant figure out is that how can I pass `f` from the calc function input to the odeint inside. It says that f isnt declared and if I put it within strings.. it doest work

When I run this function.. it doesnt work I get this error

```
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

I am not sure how to pass my equation to be integrated inside odeint

Thanks

Comment: Moar details. I've read the question three times but I don't get your problem (although the fact I'm tired might constribute). Show an example of what you want to do and explain what doesn't work and how it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please accept an answer from your previous question?

Comment: "calc(f,a,b) where x is an equation with the variable f " makes absolutely no sense and the rest of the question is very confusing at best. Try to describe the simplest example you can think of that gives you this problem.

Comment: `odeint` is not a Python built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one were to rewrite the function `calc` as follows:

```
def calc(f, a, b):
    limits = [a, b]
    integral = odeint(lambda y, x: f(x), 0, limits)

    return integral[1][0]
```

Then one may use this function thus:

```
>>> calc(lambda x: x ** 2, 0, 1)    # Integrate x ** 2 over the interval [0, 1] (expected answer: 0.333...)
0.33333335809177234
>>> calc(lambda x: x, 0, 1)         # Integrate x over the interval [0, 1] (expected answer: 0.5)
0.50000001490120016
>>> calc(lambda x: 1, 0, 1)         # Integrate 1 over the interval [0, 1] (expected answer: 1.0)
1.0
```

The `odeint` function from the `scipy.integrate` module has the signature:

```
odeint(func, y0, t, ...)
```

where: `func` is a callable that accepts parameters `y, t0, ...` and returns dy/dt at the given point; `y0` is a sequence representing initial condition of y; `t` is a sequence that represents intervals to solve for y (t0 is the first item in the sequence).

It appears that you are solving a first-order differential equation of the form dy/dx = f(x) over the interval [a, b] where y0 = 0.  In such a case, when you pass f (which accepts one argument) to the function odeint, you must wrap it in a lambda so that the passed-in function accepts two arguments (y and x--the y parameter is essentially ignored since you need not use it for a first-order differential equation).

Answer (score 1):

I assume `odeint` is some function to which you are passing the lambda function. `odeint` will presumably call the lambda and needs to pass `x` and `y` to it. So the answer is, if you want `odeint` to call the function and pass it `x` and `y`, then you need to pass `x` and `y` to `odeint` *as arguments,* in addition to the function itself.

What exactly are you trying to do here? With more details and more code, we could probably get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

x cannot have two values; therefore, if you need two values, one of them must be named something else. Rename one of your variables.

**Edit:**

(smacking forehead): In `calc(x**2, 0, 1)`, `x**2` is **not** a function - it is an expression, which gets evaluated before being passed to calc - therefore it complains about it needs to know what x is (in order to calculate x**2).

Try

```
calc(lambda x: x**2, a, b)
```

instead. This is equivalent to

```
def unnamedfunction(x):
    return x**2

calc(unnamedfunction, a, b)
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried that but in order for me to call the function calc(x**2, 0, ) it says i need to define x first and if I put it in quotes, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure because `odeint()` is not a built-in Python function so I don't know much about it, but the first argument you're passing it in your code is **not** a function that computes `x^2`. An easy way to do something like that would be to pass a `lambda` function to `calc` that does that sort of calculation. For example:

```
def calc(f, a, b):
    limits = [a, b]
    integral = odeint(f, 0, limits)

    return integral[1]

print calc(lambda x: x**2, 0, 1)
```